# Autologin not working in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, login, 15.04

after the upgrade to Kubuntu 15.04 the autologin feature isn't working anymore. I reproduced this issue on two machines, which have been upgraded from 14.10.

It's simple to reproduce: Just enable autologin in the user settings and restart. Normally the user should login automatically without entering the password, but the login screen occurs, where you have to type in the password.

It worked in 14.10, btw.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using autologin in 15.04 because I've got an nvidia optimus card and SDDM login screen doesn't work for me (after typing password it leaves me with a blank screen).

You've got to go to Configuration Settings and in the option SDDM (login screen) go to the "Advanced" label. There you've got to check "autologin" and choose the user to do it.

I've got the two things (the one you did and this one) and it's working fine.

Comment: Great that works!

Comment: It's a bit o f a mess that you have to change this in two places though ... Still the same in 15.10. I haven't checked 16.04 yet.

Comment: Yes what a mess. 16.04 and you still have to do this in 2 places....